# C++ shared_ptr inheritance memory leak

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I have a situation where I have a shared_ptr to base of a child class.

When the shared_ptr goes to delete the pointer, only the parent destructor is being called.

The parents destructor is virtual, the childs is not, although I have experimented in all combinations.

I have the program in valgrind, and it show that memory is created at the new statement when object created. And I know the parent destructor is being called, but the child's isn't.

this is the child:

```
class NetworkUserAgent : public bbs::UserAgent
{
friend class Server;

public:
    NetworkUserAgent(boost::asio::io_service &ioService, size_t _szBuffer=512u);
    ~NetworkUserAgent();

    void asyncRead();
    void doneRead(std::shared_ptr< std::vector<char> > pBuf,
                    const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t byTrans);

    void writeTo(const std::string &msg);
    void doneWrite(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t byTrans);

void close();

private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
    const size_t szBuffer;
};
```

the parent:

```
class UserAgent
{
public:
    //'structors
    UserAgent();
    virtual ~UserAgent();

    //commication
    virtual void writeTo(const std::string &msg)=0;
    std::function<void(std::string&)> dataRead;

    //user management
    void login(AccessLevel _accessLevel, int userId, const std::string &_userName);
    void logout();

    //Accessors
    AccessLevel UserAccessLevel() const;
    const std::string &UserName() const;
    const int &UserId() const;
    bool LoggedIn() const;

    //shared to allow reference to child type
    std::shared_ptr<ContextAgentData> contextAgentData;
private:
    std::string userName;
    int userId;

    AccessLevel accessLevel;
};
```

Usage:

```
void Server::reset()
{   
    shared_ptr<NetworkUserAgent> client (new NetworkUserAgent(ioService));
    acceptor_.async_accept(client->socket_,
        [=] (const boost::system::error_code &error)
            { this->clientAccepted(client, error); }
        );
}

void Server::clientAccepted(shared_ptr<NetworkUserAgent> client,
                                const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
    if(error) return;
    cout << "[] New client has connected" << endl;

    //Generalise to Network useragent
    shared_ptr<UserAgent> uaClientPtr=client;
    context->receiveUserAgent(uaClientPtr);
    client->asyncRead();
    reset();
}
```

[The rest of the code can be seen here](http://dobson156.dyndns.org/gitweb/?p=bbs.git;a=tree).

Thank You.

Also please note the code above is still a work in process.

EDIT: I was wrong the child destructor is being called,

```
NetworkUserAgent::~NetworkUserAgent()
{   
    this->close();
} 

void NetworkUserAgent::close()
{
    if(!socket_.is_open()) return; //socket is already closed
    //one or more of these functions are probably redundant  
    cout << "send request" <<endl;
    socket_.shutdown(ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
    cout << "cancel" <<endl;
    socket_.cancel();
    cout <<"close"<<endl;
    socket_.close();
    cout << "done" <<endl;
}
```

EDIT:
I have done more testing and I am afraid the problem is complex than I hoped. The destructors are being called when the items are being destroyed however, the issue is once the UserAgent enters the system it doesn't get destroyed. Something is stopping from being destroyed.

if it makes and difference the are several containers of shared_ptr to the useragent, when a contain is destroy are the destructors of the elements inside called?

Please let me know what else I can provide to fix the problem.

Comment: It's not clear from the posted code in the question when the shared pointer should be deleted.  I looked at the code in your link (which is frowned upon by the way) and there was too much there to go through.  Can you elaborate on when you expect the shared pointer to be deleted?  How are you sure the child's destructor isn't getting called (it doesn't log anything like the parent's does)?

Comment: A simplified example just to show `std::shared_ptr` handles such situations correctly: http://ideone.com/TRXVu.  I have to second Chad's question of how sure are you the correct destructors are not being called?

Comment: Please provide compilable runnable code that reproduces the problem. There are very good chances that slicing occurs somewhere in the code that you have omitted.

Comment: n.m ill try but the problem is sizable. If you look at the link I am sure you can easily download the src folder and make it. (if you click snapshot that'll do it) Thank you

Comment: Your extended problem sounds like you have a dangling reference. Somebody is holding a `shared_ptr` longer than it is supposed to, so the object is never deleted. This is easily caused by circular references... `a` holds `b`, which holds `c`, which holds `a`, so none of them ever get deleted even if nothing external references `a`. Consider using `weak_ptr` in places wher actual ownership is not neccessary. Also, your lambdas might get stored somewher along the path, and they hold copies as well.

Comment: Dennis this was exactly it. See my answer for more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a dataRead std::function in UserAgent which ended up getting set to a lambda containing a std::shared_ptr to itself stopping it self form destructing. I added a close() method and set the std::function to it default value.

Now all is well and it delete fine

Thanks for all your help any way

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your object is being sliced, though I don't have an environment to test.

Try one of these:

```
shared_ptr<UserAgent> uaClientPtr = boost::static_pointer_cast<UserAgent>(client);
shared_ptr<UserAgent> uaClientPtr = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<UserAgent>(client);
```

Comment: That would be safer, but is uneccessary here because the two types are known to inherit from one another.  No slicing should occur.

Answer (score 0):

In `void Server::reset()` `auto_ptr` is enough.

In second case I would do the followings:

```
void Server::clientAccepted(shared_ptr<NetworkUserAgent> client, const boost::system::error_code error)
{
  if(error) return;
  cout << "[] New client has connected" << endl;
  context->receiveUserAgent(client);
  client->asyncRead();
  this->reset();
}
```

Comment: This is neater but the problem remains